# How to log calls using a wrapper script when there are multiple symlinks to the executable

Tags: shell-script

Long story short: I would like to track the way in which some executables are called to track some system behaviour. Let's say that I have an executable:

```
/usr/bin/do_stuff
```

And it is actually called by a number of different names via symlink:

```
/usr/bin/make_tea -> /usr/bin/do_stuff
/usr/bin/make_coffee -> /usr/bin/do_stuff
```

and so on. Clearly, `do_stuff` is going to use the first argument it receives to determine what action is actually takes, and the rest of the arguments will be handled in the light of that.

I would like to record ever call to `/usr/bin/do_stuff` (and the full list of arguments). If there were no symlinks, I would simply move `do_stuff` to `do_stuff_real` and write a script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$0 $@" >> logfile
/usr/bin/do_stuff_real "$@"
```

However, as I know that it will examine the name that it is called by, this won't work. How does one write a script to achieve the same but still pass on to `do_stuff` the right 'executable used name'?

For the record, to avoid answers on these lines:

- I know that I can do it in C (using execve), but it would be a lot easier if I could, in this case, just use a shell script.
- I can't simply replace `do_stuff` with a logging programme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You often see this in case of utilities like `busybox`, a program that can provide most of the common unix utilities in one executable, that behaves different depending on its invocation/  `busybox` can do a whole lot of functions, `acpid` through `zcat`.

And it commonly decides what it's supposed to be doing by looking at it's `argv[0]` parameter to `main()`.  And that shouldn't be a simple comparison.  Because `argv[0]` might be something like `sleep`, or it might be `/bin/sleep` and it should decide to do the same thing.  In other words, the path is going to make things more complex.

So if things were done by the worker program right, your logging wrapper could execute from something like `/bin/realstuff/make_tea` and if the worker looks at `argv[0]` basename only, then the right function should execute.

```
#!/bin/sh -
myexec=/tmp/MYEXEC$$
mybase=`basename -- "$0"`

echo "$0 $@" >> logfile

mkdir "$myexec" || exit
ln -fs /usr/bin/real/do_stuff "$myexec/$mybase" || exit
"$myexec/$mybase" "$@"
ret=$?
rm -rf "$myexec"
exit "$ret"
```

In the example above, `argv[0]` should read something like `/tmp/MYEXEC4321/make_tea` (if 4321 was the PID for the `/bin/sh` that ran)which should trigger the basename `make_tea` behavior

If you want `argv[0]` to be an exact copy of what it would be without the wrapper, you have a tougher problem.  Because of absolute file paths beginning with `/`.  You can't make a new `/bin/sleep`  (absent `chroot` and I don't think you want to go there). As you note, you could do that with some flavor of `exec()`, but it wouldn't be a shell wrapper.

Have you considered using an alias to hit the logger and then start the base program instead of a script wrapper?  It'd only catch a limited set of events, but maybe those are the only events you care about

Comment: Had to replace basename with sed, but otherwise works well.

Comment: @NeilTownsend, with a POSIX `sh`, you can use `mybase=${0##*/}` instead of basename.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  A `basename` invocation like `basename -- foo.bar` is unfamiliar to me, and  on the Linux system I tested it on produces the result `foo.bar` which would break the script.  Are you sure that's a common method?

Comment: `basename -- foo.bar` returns `foo.bar`, `basename -- --foo--/bar` returns `bar` as expected. `basename "$foo"` only works if you can guarantee `$foo` doesn't start with a `-`. The general syntax to invoke a command with arbitrary arguments is `cmd -x -y -- "$argument"`. `cmd "$argument"` is wrong unless you mean `cmd "$option_or_arg"`. Now, some commands (including some historic implementations of `basename`) don't support `--` so you may sometimes have to choose between  portability and reliability.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `exec -a` (as found in `bash`, `ksh93`, `zsh`, `mksh`, `yash` but not POSIX yet) that is used to specify an `argv[0]` to a command being executed:

```
#! /bin/bash -
printf '%s\n' "$0 $*" >> /some/log
exec -a "$0" /usr/bin/do_stuff_real "$@"
```

Note that that `$0` is *not* the `argv[0]` that the command receives. It is the path of the script as passed to `execve()` (and which is passed as argument to `bash`), but that's likely to be enough for your purpose.

As an example, if `make_tea` was invoked as:

```
execv("/usr/bin/make_tea", ["make_tea", "--sugar=2"])
```

As a shell would typically do when invoking the command by name (looking up the executable in `$PATH`), the wrapper would to:

```
execv("/usr/bin/do_stuff_real", ["/usr/bin/make_tea", "--sugar=2"])
```

That's not:

```
execv("/usr/bin/do_stuff_real", ["make_tea", "--sugar=2"])
```

but that's good enough as `do_stuff_real` knows it's meant to make tea.

Where that would be a problem is if `do_stuff` was invoked as:

```
execv("/usr/bin/do_stuff", ["/usr/bin/make_tea", "--sugar=2"])
```

as that would be translated to:

```
execv("/usr/bin/do_stuff_real", ["/usr/bin/do_stuff", "--sugar=2"])
```

That would not happen during normal operations, but note that our wrapper does something like that.

On most systems, the `argv[0]` as passed to the script is lost once the interpreter (here `/bin/bash`) is executed ([the `argv[0]` of the interpreter on most systems is the path given on the she-bang line](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#results)) so there's nothing a shell script can do about it.

If you wanted to pass the `argv[0]` along, you'd need to compile an executable. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
   /* add logging */
   execve("/usr/bin/do_stuff_real", argv, envp);
   perror("execve");
   return 127;
}
```

Comment: +1: This would be the right answer, except that the shell on the system I'm trying to work on doesn't provide the -a option for exec ...

Comment: @NeilTownsend You could do something similar with `perl` or `python` if available. Older versions of `zsh` didn't support `exec -a`, but you can always use `ARGV0=the-argv-0 cmd args` instead.

Comment: It's a busybox based machine, so the shell seems to be ash, which doesn't seem to have the -a flag. Or, at least, on this version. As I'm in the process of working on the firmware, and I don't have a clear enough grip on it to do anything presumptuous, I am trying to avoid adding too much to it just to understand how it starts up. I think ARGV0 is a zsh only thing?

Comment: @NeilTownsend, yes that's a zsh-only thing. I meant that if you had `zsh` (though now you've made it clear that you haven't) but it was too old, you could still use `ARGV0` there.

Comment: Fair enough - If I could tick your answer for being 'brilliant but didn't actually work for my obscure situation" I would.